# Export: '0.0' : not a valid identifier in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am fairly new to Bash scripting and am trying to set environment and libraries to use and then build a particular script. Here is the Bash script I wrote:

```
#! /bin/bash

export DISPLAY :0.0
#setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/szip2.1/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
# above line should be equivalent to
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH "/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

module load Szip/2.1-gmpolf-2015
module load cuda/6.5

#while ( 1 )
  cd /home/sbansal6/misr-stereo-2013.11.24
  /home/sbansal6/misr-stereo-2013.11.24/bin/misr-stereo /home/sbansal6/ellipsoids/0034007 AN AA
#end
```

And here is what I get as the error:

```
[sbansal6@cg-gpu01 STEREO]$ ./mstdrv.csh
./mstdrv.csh: line 3: export: `:0.0': not a valid identifier
./mstdrv.sh: line 6: export: `/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:/sw/cuda/6.5/lib64:/sw/EasyBuild/software/Szip/2.1-gmpolf-2015/lib:/sw/EasyBuild/software/ScaLAPACK/2.0.2-gmpich-2015-OpenBLAS-0.2.14-LAPACK-3.5.0/lib:/sw/EasyBuild/software/FFTW/3.3.4-gmpich-2015/lib:/sw/EasyBuild/software/OpenBLAS/0.2.14-GCC-4.9.2-binutils-2.25-LAPACK-3.5.0/lib:/sw/EasyBuild/software/MPICH/3.1.4-GCC-4.9.2-binutils-2.25/lib:/sw/EasyBuild/software/GCC/4.9.2-binutils-2.25/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2:/sw/EasyBuild/software/GCC/4.9.2-binutils-2.25/lib64:/sw/EasyBuild/software/GCC/4.9.2-binutils-2.25/lib:/sw/binutils-2.25/lib': not a valid identifier
/home/sbansa16/misr-stereo-2013.11.24/bin/misr-stereo:error while loading shared libraries: libglut.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am basically trying to add the libraries from Szip and Cuda in my environment and then build a C++ program which is at the path I wrote later. I do understand that the last error that I got which said error while loading shared libraries: libglut.so.3 is because I don't have that library in my libraries.

I am sorry if this question is trivial. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I have also tried using setenv from csh but it is still not working.

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: Its the first image.

Comment: Please don't post images, it's very hard to search and to copy/paste for people to use to help you.  Instead please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44331945/edit) your question to include the code formatted as a code block.

Comment: Should be `export DISPLAY=:0.0`.

Comment: It still gives me the same error

Answer (score 1):

Bash syntax for setting an environment variable would be:

```
export NAME=value
```

or

```
NAME=value
export NAME
```

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work. It says that `./mstdrv.csh: line 3: export: '=' : not a valid indentifier.`

Comment: I copied my entire code in a .bash file and a .sh file and tried running it but it still gives the same error. Please let me know what  I am doing wrong and I am sorry if this question is trivial. I am really new to shell scripting.